# Updating Data From One Activity to Another

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing an android application that uses telnet communication and receives data every second (ActivityTelnet). I would like to address some of these data in another activity (Activity1). But when I'm in Activity1, I do not know how to receive and update the data, I do not even know if it is possible. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please show us your code, or what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of bus to deliver your data.

One of them is the `LocalBroadcastManager`. You get an instance of it from the system in ActivityTelnet and use it to communicate with a `BroadcastReceiver` in the other Activity1.

**Broadcasting something:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("someFilter");
intent.putExtra("itemName", someParcelable);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You may pass primitive types and objects, provided that they implement the `Parcelable` interface. Check [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for more information on it.

**Receiving the broadcast:**

```
// declare your receiver
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // do something
    }
};
// add this to your #onCreate(Bundle) in Activity1
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("someFilter"));
```

Pay attention to the `IntentFilter` you're using when creating the Intent and when registering the Receiver. They **must** match.

You may also use other buses, such as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) by Square.